# How to convert a String into list of Integer in Scala

Tags: list, scala, flatmap

I  have a string `1,3,5-10` and I have to convert this string into a list of integer in scala.
The list will like this --->>.  `List(1,3,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

How will be the best way to convert a string list into an integer list using `flatMap`.

or What will the minimal line of code in *Scala* to do this.

This is the code I have tried to achieve it but I wanted a better way to do so

```
val selectedNumberList: mutable.MutableList[Int] = mutable.MutableList[Int]()
val numbersList = "1,3,5-10".split(",").toList
for(i <- 0 until numbersList.size ){
if(numbersList(i).contains("-")){
val splitNumberToList = numbersList(i).split("-").toList
    for(j <- splitNumberToList.head.toInt to splitNumberToList.last.toInt){
      selectedNumberList += j
    }
}else{
    selectedNumberList += numbersList(i).toInt
  }
}
```

The above code does not use the flat map but can we do this in a better way.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What kind of inputs would you expect. How would you handle errors? Also, please show any kind of effort, this is not a free code service.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `flatMap`?

Comment: Requirement is incomplete.  For instance, could there be multiple ranges,  negative numbers?

Comment: @Jatin you'll probably end up using flatMap anyway, but it is a bit of a weird requirement to _have to_ use flatMap.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shortest line of code for Scala 2.13 that for the input sample produces an expected output using `flatMap`:

```
scala> "1,3,5-10".split(',')
                 .toList
                 .flatMap{case s"$a-$b" => a.toInt to b.toInt;
                          case a        => a.toInt::Nil}
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

P.S. For error handling (if it is required) you can catch exceptions or use `Try` which do this underhood.

P.P.S. Code was formatted as a one-liner for easier counting of its length

Comment: This isn't very safe; it doesn't handle any error cases if the input String is dodgy.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley In addition to `Try`, Both negative numbers and non-numeric characters can also be handled by adding extra `case`s.

Comment: I would just suggest editing this answer and change the style to usual Scala style to improve readability.

Comment: yes this is good, just define a default case, it will handle other random string.

Comment: @jrook Scala is both object oriented and functional. its the Style of Scala :)

Comment: @Hackaholic, I just meant adhering to basic readability guidelines like [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/indentation.html#line-wrapping) to make the answer more accessible.

Comment: @Hackaholic being functional or OO has nothing to do with it; this doesn't follow Scala style guidelines. Almost anything can be "short" or a "one-liner" if you replace all new lines with semicolons and delete all unnecessary whitespace until it's condense but hard to read - it might look short and compile, but that doesn't mean it's good code (from a style/standards perspective).

Answer (score 1):

Here's somewhere to start:

```scala
import scala.util.Try

def validateRegex(input: String): Try[Unit] = Try(if(!input.matches("((\\d+-\\d+|\\d+)($|,(\\s+)?))+")) throw new Exception(""))
def validateRange(input: String): Try[Unit] = Try {
  val pattern = "\\d+-\\d+".r
  (pattern findAllIn input).toList.map(_.split("-").map(_.toInt)).map(_.toList).map {
    case a :: b :: Nil if a >= b => throw new Exception("")
    case _ =>
  }
}

def validateInput(input: String): Boolean = {
  val list: List[Try[Unit]] = List(
    validateRegex(input),
    validateRange(input)
  )
  !list.exists(_.isFailure)
}

def inToOut(input: String): List[Int] = {
  if(validateInput(input)) input.split(",\\s?").flatMap {
    case r if r.contains("-") =>
      val s = r.split("-").map(_.toInt)
      (s(0) to s(1)).toList
    case i => List(i.toInt)
  }.toList else List()
}
```

You call `inToOut` with your String and it either spits out an empty List (if your String is invalid) or a populated List if everything is formatted correctly.

### However

This is incomplete.

- This isn't very condense - you can shorten it considerably, but this code is laid out in a way that is (hopefully) understandable.
- You'll need to add in more (or different) error handling - your question doesn't specify any sort of error handling, so I've implemented a couple of validations that you *could* do to get you going but you'll need to decide what the limits of your function are (String format, range rules, ordering, duplicate values, etc).
- There's probably a quicker way of implementing this without throwing an exception every time something goes wrong. Depends on your implementation; I'll leave this up to you.
- I haven't accounted for negative numbers (again something for you to implement if you need to).

---

Anyway, here's an implementation of it working with some success and failure examples: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FmUsQZQGQIC6X6JRmFLVjg

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code and it is working fine for me now.

```
val numbers = "1,3,5-10".split(",").toList.flatMap{
  case x if x.contains("-") =>
    val k = x.split("-")
    k.head.toInt to k(1).toInt
  case a => a.toInt::Nil
}
```

Comment: Pretty similar to the answer from @AndriyPlokhotnyuk, but not as clean and concise.

Comment: Yes it is similar to his but I had to modify that code because it was giving error of "Type mismatch" on my system

Comment: Possible you have some earlier version of Scala

Comment: I have changed the scala version to 2.13.0, still, the error was there hence I have to modify it.

Comment: It should work with Scala 2.13.0, here is a welcome string from my REPL: `Welcome to Scala 2.13.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_232).`

Comment: Again, this isn't safe as it doesn't account for non-numbers, negative numbers, invalid ranges, bad String formatting, etc.